# Not clear about the "Checked exception" explanation in "functional programming in Scala"

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, checked-exceptions

In the book of "Functional programming in Scala", there are some words talk about the "checked exception":

> Checked exceptions
>
> Java’s checked exceptions at least force a decision about whether to handle or reraise an error, but they result in significant boilerplate for callers. More importantly, they don’t work for higher-order functions, which can’t possibly be aware of the specific exceptions that could be raised by their arguments. For example, consider the map function we defined for List:
>
> `def map[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B]`
>
> This function is clearly useful, highly generic, and at odds with the use of checked exceptions — we can’t have a version of map for every single checked exception that could possibly be thrown by `f`. Even if we wanted to do this, how would map even know what exceptions were possible? This is why generic code, even in Java, so often resorts to using RuntimeException or some common checked Exception type.

I read this section several times, but still not clear why **checked exception** is not working for **higher-order functions**.

Could someone give some examples to make it more clear?

Answer (score 6):

Try to write the function `map<A, B>` in Java. At some point you'll find yourself needing to call your mapping function. Your mapping function could be *anything* and throw any kind of exception that it likes. The function `map` cannot include in its signature all the possible exceptions that the mapper can throw because it has *no idea what it is*. It's impossible to write the type signature of `map` with checked exceptions.

Suppose the signature of `map` was something like `Colletion<B> map<A, B>(Function<A,B>, Collection<A>)`. Now suppose we call it as `map(x -> throw new IOException, Lists.of(1,2,3))`. Since `IOException` is checked, it should appear in the signature of `map` but until you called `map`, it had no idea that it *could* throw this type of exception.